# Slot filling for intent - Google Actions Builder

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant, actionbuilder

In the Dialogflow, we have a option like slot filling when a particular intent is matched, the Dialogflow agent continues collecting all the required parameters (which is specified by us within the intent).

[image: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-actions-parameters]

The same option in Alexa too.

But I can't able to find this same option in Google Actions Builder. In the scenes, they are having slot filling but this will execute before the intent matching. So it is not checking for the particular intent.

[image: Slot Filling is above the user intent handling!]

How can I validate whether the required type is satisfied or not when the intent is matching?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an intent in Actions Builder, there is a section **Add intent parameters**. In this section you can provide a parameter using a *Type* you have previously defined in **Develop > Types**.

Once you have an intent parameter name defined, you can use it's associated values within the training phrases of your intent, similar to Dialogflow.

If you have an intent defined with intent parameters, you can add this intent to a Scene under **User intent Handling**, enabling the intent to be matched along with the intent parameter data. There is no need to add slot filling to the Scene.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I got your point, but my query is bit different that "How can I ensure that one particular parameter in that intent is a mandatory one for execution of that intent?"